# Why does one Virtual App require IUSR access to avoid 401.3 Status Code

Tags: iis, http-status-code-401

I have an IIS-hosted website that has 11 web services each running under their own virtual application.  For each, the underlying folder is a child of the hosting site's folder.  All have existed for a year or more, but web service A may never have been actually tested when deployed, the others have been actively used.

We've recently decided to use Service A, made code changes and deployed.  Attempting to reach the service throws a 401.3 authorization error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

I've compared virtually everything I can find in IIS (App Pool settings, ASP.NET, IIS and Management Features, etc.) about Service A and it's peers with nothing seeming different.

Once I added IUSR to Service A's permissions, it responded normally.  However, none of the other services have this account among their permissions, yet work fine.

Can someone shed a light on why a single virtual app that very closely mirrors ten others would need IUSR specifically listed among granted users?

Comment: The ISUR user for anonymous authentication does not have sufficient rights to read the files for the user portal. select your site->authtication->Right click on "Anonymous Authentication" and select "Edit". compare this for all the services. or you could try to Enable auditing to see where the access denied error is occurring [link](https://forums.iis.net/post/2157904.aspx)

Comment: you could try to Enable auditing to see where the access denied error is occurring  [link](https://forums.iis.net/post/2157904.aspx)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal at some point I can.  It's only happening in a production environment and there are hoops to jump through to make changes once live.  Since it's working with IUSR, I'm not sure when I'll get opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

The [IUSR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4466942/understanding-identities-in-iis) is used by the anonymous authentication. If you have enabled anonymous auth in the ServiceA, that contents is accessed by IUSR. Is the authentication setting different from ServiceA and other websites.

Comment: Thanks, chyonek.  That seems like it should work.  But I've compared two functioning services with the one that is not working.  Both have IUSR as the Authentication Credentials but neither have granted permissions to IUSR.  They both have the identical set of users and permissions as Service A.

Comment: Are all services enabled only for anonymous authentication? If only Windows auth is enabled, IUSR access permission is not required. Because worker threads work by authenticated account.

Comment: thanks again.  Yes the others are also set up with Anonymous Auth enabled with ASP.NET Impersonation and Forms Authentication both disabled.  No other entries are in the Authentication feature.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any difference of  physical path folder acls for each site? IUSR is a member of the local Users group.